# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am learning tkinter from the book "Programming Python". In the section dedicated for scroll bars I have faced a problem that I was not able to fix.

```
from tkinter import *

class ScrolledList(Frame):
    def __int__(self, options, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.makeWidgets(options)

    def hendleList(self, event):
        index=self.listbox.curselection()
        label=self.listbox.get(index)
        self.runCommand(label)

    def makeWidget(self, options):
        sbar=Scrollbar(self)
        list=Listbox(self, relief=SUNKEN)
        sbar.config(command=list.yview)
        list.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
        sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        list.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        pos=0
        for label in options:
            list.insert(pos, label)
            pos+=1
        list.bind('<Double-1>', self.handleList)
        self.listbox = list

    def runCommand(self, selection):
        print('You selected:', selection)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options=[('Luberjack-{}'.format(x)) for x in range(20)]
    ScrolledList(options).mainloop()
```

This is my code and the Error being arised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled3/venv/scr_list.py", line 34, in <module>
ScrolledList(options).mainloop()
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2741, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'frame', cnf, {}, extra)
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2289, in __init__
BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2259, in _setup
self.tk = master.tk
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

There was a similar problem before, but I have already called `Frame` `__init__` in my code

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just edited

Comment: I checked that, but it didn`t solve my problem

Comment: You didn't follow the advice of their code though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few spelling errors: `def __int__`, `makeWidget` and  `hendleList`. With those corrected it runs without error:

```
from tkinter import *

class ScrolledList(Frame):
    def __init__(self, options, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.makeWidgets(options)

    def handleList(self, event):
        index=self.listbox.curselection()
        label=self.listbox.get(index)
        self.runCommand(label)

    def makeWidgets(self, options):
        sbar=Scrollbar(self)
        list=Listbox(self, relief=SUNKEN)
        sbar.config(command=list.yview)
        list.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
        sbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        list.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        pos=0
        for label in options:
            list.insert(pos, label)
            pos+=1
        list.bind('<Double-1>', self.handleList)
        self.listbox = list

    def runCommand(self, selection):
        print('You selected:', selection)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options=[('Luberjack-{}'.format(x)) for x in range(20)]
    ScrolledList(options).mainloop()
```